# Django Form fields change to mandatory

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I faced a strange problem that has hold me for 2 hour.

I create a simple form but when I pass it to Template , I see that their fields are mandatory(I can't leave them empty) although I just want that only email field be mandatory.

my Form is **KarjooInformationEditForm**:

```
class GeneralInformationEditForm(forms.Form):
    ffdfdfdf=forms.CharField(max_length=50);
    email=forms.EmailField();
    #email.required=True;
    email.error_messages={
        'required':
            'پست الکترونیکی نمی تواند خالی باشد'
        ,
    }
    email.label='پست الکترونیکی';

    telephone=forms.CharField(max_length=30);
    telephone.label='شماره تماس'

class KarjooInformationEditForm(GeneralInformationEditForm):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=30);
    name.label='نام'
    family=forms.CharField(max_length=30);
    family.label='نام خانوادگی'
    age=forms.IntegerField();
    age.label='سن'
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30);
    city.label='شهر'
    address=forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.Textarea);
    address.label='آدرس'
```

I would be appreciate for any bit of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `requred` to `False` in all fields except email:

```
ffdfdfdf=forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check out django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#core-field-arguments